# How do I render a url from a post request form in a show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, post

1 Please help me render a post request of website(url) into a working button. Error message is [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pseM2.png)

2. I only put in all the relevant code to make sure you guys can get a feel for where I am at. I'm new here. Thanks!

## routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

 root 'pages#index'

 resources :restaurants
 resources :reviews
 resources :pages

 match 'index', to: 'pages#index', via: :get
   match 'location', to: 'pages#location', via: :get
 end
```

## Restaurant_Controller.rb

```
  class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
     def index
   @restaurants = Restaurant.all
    end


   def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new
   end

  def create
   @restaurant = Restaurant.create!(restaurant_params)
   redirect_to @restaurant
   end

   def show
  @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
  @restaurants = Restaurant.all
 end


   private

  def restaurant_params
   params.require(:restaurant).permit(:name, :description, :address1,
  :city, :state, :zipcode, :phone, :email, :img_url)
    end
   end
```

## new.html.erb

```
 <!-- Page Content -->
 <div class="container" id="holder">

 <!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <h1 class="page-header"> Reviewing Restaurant....</h1>
   </div>
 </div>

  <!-- Contact Form -->
  <!-- In order to set the email address and subject line for the   contact form go to the bin/contact_me.php file. -->

 <%= form_for @restaurant do |f| %>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="control-group form-group">

    <div class="controls">
      <label>Name:</label> <br>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label>Description:</label> <br>
      <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control"%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label>Photo:</label>
      <%= f.text_field :img_url, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label>Address:</label>
      <%= f.text_field :address1, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label>City:</label>
      <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control"%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label>State:</label>
      <%= f.text_field :state, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label>Zipcode:</label>
      <%= f.text_field :zipcode, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label>Phone:</label>
      <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label>Website:</label>
      <%= f.text_field :website, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- restaruant will not go to show page -->
  <div id="success"></div>
  <!-- For success/fail messages -->
  <%=button_to 'Create Restaruant Review',   restaurants_path(@restaurant), :method => :post , class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  </div>



   <% end %>

  </div>
```

## show.html.erb

```
    <li class="li_spacing"> <%= button_to "Website",  @restaurant.website ,  
 form: { target: '_blank', rel: 'noreferrer'} , :class => "btn btn-primary" %></li>
```

## error image

Comment: You should be making a `POST` to `/restaurants` (a default CRUD and RESTful behavior). Looks like your form construct is wrong. Can you please add how are you creating your in `new.html.erb`

Comment: My form works because all the seed data works.                                               `  <div class="navbar-header" id= "newReview">
      <%= link_to "Write A Restaurant Review!", new_restaurant_path%>
    </div> `

Comment: I mean the first place to look would be `POST` location. The form is submitting the form-data to route that doesn't exists

Comment: Also, the form doesn't seem to have a submit button. Not sure whats the use case of `<%=button_to 'Create Restaruant Review',   restaurants_path(@restaurant), :method => :post , class: "btn btn-primary"%>` is, but the form should have a submit option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We need the "error text" in the question itself, not at the end of a link. Links rot then break, so when it does we won't have information needed to understand your question. Bold text is akin to yelling; Use it very sparingly. What is "error image"?